# How to measure service methods using spring boot 2 and micrometer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I started my first project on Spring Boot 2 (RC1). Thanks to the already good documentation this has not been to hard coming from Spring Boot 1.x.

However now that I want to integrate metrics I'm stumbeling. As far as I was able to find currently there is only documentation for the metrics shipped by default. But I'd like to also measure service level execution time as well as the time used in dynamodb.

**EDIT**
I'm looking for a solution using Micrometer, the library used in the new actuator library shipped with spring-boot 2.

Is there any guide on how this should be done? From [this](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/395) I read that there is no easy annotation based solution for arbitrary spring beans yet. Could s.o. give me an example / link to documentation on how a method like below could be metered?

```
@Service
@Timed
public class MyService {
    public void doSomething() {
        ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's a little sample which should get you going. There's more variants to `Timer.record()` which aren't shown here. (Also: Field injection only used for brevity.)
You don't have to put the called methods name into a tag. You can also make it part of the metric name itself. Just wanted to show what you could do.

**Update 2018-03-12:** As of `Micrometer 1.0.0` a `TimedAspect` has been introduced so that you can also use the `@Timed` annotation. For now you need to register the `Bean` yourself. (You need to be cautious though when you have custom `@Timed` annotations on your Spring-MVC or Jersey resources.) This was already mentioned by [Michal Stepan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097423/michal-stepan) in a follow-up [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193908/9071502).

```
package io.github.mweirauch.micrometered.eval;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.Sample;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class TimingStuff {

    @Service
    static class MyService {

        @Autowired
        private MeterRegistry registry;

        public void helloManual() {
            // you can keep a ref to this; ok to call multiple times, though
            Timer timer = Timer.builder("myservice").tag("method", "manual").register(registry);

            // manually do the timing calculation
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            doSomething();
            timer.record(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }

        public void helloSupplier() {
            Timer timer = Timer.builder("myservice").tag("method", "supplier").register(registry);

            // execution of the method is timed internally
            timer.record(() -> doSomething());
        }

        public void helloSample() {
            Timer timer = Timer.builder("myservice").tag("method", "sample").register(registry);

            // records time taken between Sample creation and registering the
            // stop() with the given Timer
            Sample sample = Timer.start(registry);
            doSomething();
            sample.stop(timer);
        }

        // TimedAspect adds "class" and "method" tags
        @Timed(value = "myservice.aspect")
        public void helloAspect() {
            doSomething();
        }

        private void doSomething() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //
            }
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Bean
    TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void postConstruct() {
        myService.helloManual();
        myService.helloSupplier();
        myService.helloSample();
        myService.helloAspect();
    }

}
```

In case you go for Prometheus, you'd end up with something like that:

```
# HELP myservice_seconds  
# TYPE myservice_seconds summary
myservice_seconds_count{application="micrometered",method="manual",} 4.0
myservice_seconds_sum{application="micrometered",method="manual",} 0.200378014
myservice_seconds_max{application="micrometered",method="manual",} 0.050115291
myservice_seconds_count{application="micrometered",method="supplier",} 4.0
myservice_seconds_sum{application="micrometered",method="supplier",} 0.200393455
myservice_seconds_max{application="micrometered",method="supplier",} 0.05011635
myservice_seconds_count{application="micrometered",method="sample",} 4.0
myservice_seconds_sum{application="micrometered",method="sample",} 0.200527005
myservice_seconds_max{application="micrometered",method="sample",} 0.050250191
# HELP myservice_aspect_seconds  
# TYPE myservice_aspect_seconds summary
myservice_aspect_seconds_count{application="micrometered",class="io.github.mweirauch.micrometered.eval.TimingStuff$MyService",method="helloAspect",} 4.0
myservice_aspect_seconds_sum{application="micrometered",class="io.github.mweirauch.micrometered.eval.TimingStuff$MyService",method="helloAspect",} 0.201824272
myservice_aspect_seconds_max{application="micrometered",class="io.github.mweirauch.micrometered.eval.TimingStuff$MyService",method="helloAspect",} 0.051014296
```

Comment: Update snippet with imports.

Comment: getting error: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around'

Comment: @user_x You need to add aspectj to your dependencies. Easiest is using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop`.

Answer (score 54):

`@io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed` annotation seems to be out of order for custom calls due to reduction of scope, at it is mentioned [in link in your question](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/395).

You need to manually setup an Aspect:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AutoTimingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
        }
}
```

This way method like this:

```
@Timed("GET_CARS")
public List<Car> getCars(){
        return Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

will result in `GET_CARS` metric in `/actuator/metrics` (default) endpoint.

Comment: I could not get this to work with Spring Boot 2.0.4. Any idea?

Comment: It works for me in spring-boot 2 and I can see output in prometheus endpoint

Comment: Micrometer’s Spring Boot configuration does not recognize @Timed on arbitrary methods.

Comment: @vanillasugar By default, yes. However, the configuration that is specified by the poster enables this for arbitrary methods.

Comment: Only arbitrary methods in another bean. If called from within the bean, it will not work.

Comment: Because without calling from outside, no proxy is traversed and no aop.