# Spring-boot micrometer timer() how does it work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am new to using spring-boot metrics and started with micrometer. I couldn't find good examples(the fact that its new) for performing timer Metrics in my spring-boot app. I am using spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE dependency .
But running spring-boot server and starting jconsole, I didn't see it showing Metrics (MBeans),so I also explicitly included below dependency:

```
spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.2.RELEASE
```

Also micrometer dependency : `'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-jmx:latest'`
After adding actuator ,it does show Metrics folder but I do not see my timer(app.timer)attribute in the list. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions appreciated!

Below code snippet:

```
MeterRegistry registry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Timer timer = registry.timer("app.timer", "type", "ping");
timer.record(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This works:

```
Metrics.timer("app.timer").record(()-> {

 didSomeLogic;
 long t = timeOccurred - timeScheduled;
 LOG.info("recorded timer = {}", t);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-getting-started) of the docs. I tweaked it to be more similar to what you want. You just have to register your `Timer` with the `AutoConfigured` `MetricRegistry`:

```
@Component
public class SampleBean {

    private final Timer timer;

    public SampleBean(MeterRegistry registry) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.timer = registry.timer("app.timer", "type", "ping");
    }

    public void handleMessage(String message) {
        timer.record(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks dovmo  for the reply. I'll check this out. But can I use timer() Metric without creating registry? Something like Metrics.timer().record(). I don't think I want to create a custom registry . I just want to be able to record timer metrics for my app.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me revise. You want to use the one that's autoconfigured

Comment: So I was able to make it work with above code(Edited at the end of post), kindly check. In JMX console, I can now see the metric details but no visuals graphs, so not sure if there is a better way to understand these metric visually.

Comment: Great! If you could upvote and choose my answer as correct, then that would be great. In terms of the visualization, JMX will only give you the instantaneous values. Other monitoring systems plug in to JMX to make the visualizations. See here for the list of monitoring tools you can use (even if just locally) to view that data:
https://micrometer.io/docs; Atlas, Datadog, etc.

Comment: I tried to upvote but unfortunately since I have less reputations it might not show. It's recorded though as per notification I received. Thanks!

Comment: Better to use System.nanoTime as currentTimeMillis may be updated during execution, for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258891/2580829

Comment: true, that handleMessage() does the main part.

Answer (score 11):

This could be. If you are using Spring Boot 2, just call Timer wherever you want, no need to use a constructor.

```
public void methodName(){
    //start
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();// Google Guava
    
    // your job here
         
    // check time
    Metrics.timer("metric-name",
            "tag1", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), //class
            "tag2", new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()) // method 
            .record(stopwatch.stop().elapsed());
}
```

Comment: This is the example I was looking for, regarding how to use not only Metrics.timer() (that I use instead via the annotation @Timer on the method in Spring Boot 2.3.4, since it is for me simpler), but also Metrics.summary(), with which I log in Prometheus the size of the elaborated data.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to output the timer information with Spring Boot Micrometer, is to add the annotation `io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed` to the method whose execution to track, and add in the ApplicationContext class, or in any class that has the `@Configuration` annotation, the following method:

```
@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
    return new TimedAspect(registry);
}
```

After that, a working example would be:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save", produces = "application/json")
@Timed(description = "Time spent saving results")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> saveResults(@CookieValue(name = "JSESSIONID") String sessionId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(importer.saveResults(sessionId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193908/5538923 .

Comment: This doesn't allow adding dynamic tags within the execution, though

Comment: You're missing the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation. Is it still necessary these days?