# System.currentTimeMillis() method: returning huge value for execution time then actual execution time

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have added a code in my java code to calculate the time to finish the program.

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and

```
final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

finally I print the difference between the endtime and starttime.

```
System.out.println("The total time needed is :" + (endTime - startTime));
```

But when I run the program the output says

```
The total time needed is :45194
```

If the time is in milliseconds that's 45.194 seconds but my program completed in like 3 seconds at max. So help me comprehend this huge number 45194 which is the output.

EDIT :

Here's the whole code

```
 package com.example.TestUnit;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SurfacePeak {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SurfacePeak s = new SurfacePeak();
        int l,m,a,b, peak;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the matrix dimensions :");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();

        int[][] x = new int [a][b];

        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix : ");

        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                x[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }




        l = 0 ; m = b - 1;


        peak = s.GetPeak(x, l, m, a, b);
        System.out.println("The peak is : " + peak);

        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();



        System.out.println("The total time needed is :" + (endTime - startTime));


    }

    private int GetPeak(int[][] y, int l, int m, int a, int b) {

        int midCol = (l+m)/2;
        int maxRowindex = GetColMax(y,midCol,a);



        if(midCol != 0 && midCol != b-1) {
            if(y[maxRowindex][midCol - 1] > y[maxRowindex][midCol]) {

                m = midCol - 1;
                return GetPeak(y,l,m,a,b);
            }else if(y[maxRowindex][midCol + 1] > y[maxRowindex][midCol]) {

                l = midCol + 1;
                return GetPeak(y,l,m,a,b);
            }
        }else if(a==2 && b == 2 && midCol == 0 || midCol == b-1) {
            if(y[maxRowindex][midCol+1] > y[maxRowindex][midCol] && midCol == 0 )
                return y[maxRowindex][midCol+1];
            else if(midCol == b -1 && y[maxRowindex][midCol-1]>y[maxRowindex][midCol])
                return y[maxRowindex][midCol-1];
        }

        return y[maxRowindex][midCol];
    }


    private int GetColMax(int[][] a, int mid, int row) {

        int max = a[0][mid], maxRow = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            if(a[i][mid] >= max) {
                max = a[i][mid];
                maxRow = i;
            }

        }

        return  maxRow;

    }
```

Here's the output also

```
    Enter the matrix dimensions :
4 4 
Enter the elements of the matrix : 
10 8 10 10 14 56 78 12 90 99 24 300 6 8 1 2
The peak is : 99
The total time needed is :25235
```

The last time I ran it showed 25235 ... which is much more compared to the actual time.

EDIT:  It was so stupid of me to start timing before the user inputs which was the main problem here.

Comment: can you please share the code along with the Timestamp declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure the a time-span in seconds using System.currentTimeMillis()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317750/how-to-measure-the-a-time-span-in-seconds-using-system-currenttimemillis)

Comment: Your code looks correct, so sorry, I cannot explain.

Comment: Are you dealing with user inputs in your code?

Comment: The only possible explanation I could think of is uf domeone adjusted the system clock between your two calls. Can you reproduce the behaviour? How many times?

Comment: Can you paste you code here because the stuff provided by you is not enough to find a solution

Comment: yes I am using user inputs .. I will paste the whole code

Comment: @ErHarshRathore I have added the code

Comment: Are you sure you're timing what you think you're timing? You get the start time before prompting the user for input, so the running time will include the time spent by the user typing in his/her responses.

Comment: @Kenster okay I understand .. let me try

Comment: @Kenster it was so stupid of me ... you are right. OMG.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as shown is correct. Though it would have been convenient to see the start and stop values to verify.

## Clock reset

Your computer hardware clock must have corrected or been reset during execution.

This can happen if your host OS is configured to check in with a time server. This configuration is the norm nowadays, as having an internet connection is so common.

The clock could be reset remotely by a sysadmin in some corporate IT scenarios.

## `System.nanoTime`

You can avoid this issue of clock reset by using calls to [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) if your goal is [micro-benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)). This command taps into an incrementing count of time since some unspecified moment, often the launch of the JVM or the booting of the host OS. This count of nanoseconds is ever-increasing until reaching the limit of 64-bits (292 years).

This count is *not* tied to the calendar, does not know about dates or time zones or offset-from-UTC.

Caveat: While ever-increasing the number is not necessarily precise. Today’s conventional clock hardware is not accurate beyond microseconds (if that).

## JMH & JEP 230 for benchmarking

If your goal is micro-[benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) rather than tracking moments in history, see the [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) tool. Now added as a feature to [OpenJDK 12](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/12/) in [JEP 230](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230). Discussed in [this article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/04/jep-230-microbenchmark-suite/).

Comment: Okay but somewhere at stack overflow they mentioned that System.nanoTime messes with multithreading cpu's and they suggested System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was stupid of me to set the clock the running before the user inputs.

Comment: @SandipanMajhi The `System.nanoTime` simply tracks elapsed time but without tying to the calendar’s date and time-of-day. It tracks a count since some unspecified moment, often the launch of the JVM or the launch of the host OS. It is indeed a good way to track elapsed time. I have never heard of the vague issues you mentioned in your comment. Furthermore, `System.currentTimeMillis` is now outmoded by the *java.time* classes, specifically replaced by [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) .

Comment: @ Basil Bourque .. Thank you I will be using System.nanoTime ... for time elapsed

Answer (score 0):

I edited my program after all. As many suggested I foolishly started timing before the user inputs.

I tried started timing after the user inputs and I finally got 13 milliseconds.

Comment: one more change should be there in System.out.println("The total time needed is :" + (endTime - startTime));  change this line to System.out.println("The total time needed is :" + ((endTime - startTime)/1000.0)+"sec");

Comment: Yeah... okay... @ErHarshRathore